# spring authorization server and OpenID4VCI

Tags: spring-security, spring-authorization-server

according OpenID4VCI spec (https://openid.net/specs/openid-4-verifiable-credential-issuance-1_0.html) they define:
Credential Issuer:
An entity that issues Verifiable Credentials. Also called Issuer. In the context of this specification, the Credential Issuer acts as an OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server

I guess this means that spring authorization server can be 'extended' to support issuance of VC. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: It looks like a correct understanding to me (but I haven't fully reviewed that spec). However, you'd need to do a lot of "extending" :) by the look of things since there are numerous extension points defined there.

Comment: i also don't understand all the aspect (at this point) but it looks like 'credential issuer' can be different component which just uses 'spring authorization server' as OAuth2.0 authorization server. 
I'm looking at point 10.2 in the spec (credential issuer metadata), credential issuer must expose an endpoint (metadata/discovery) that returns different properties. One of them is:
authorization_server: OPTIONAL. Identifier of the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server (as defined in [RFC8414]) the Credential Issuer relies on for authorization..

Comment: I guess this way most of the implementation will be done on the new component (credential issuer), however there are still few places in Spring authorization server which should be extended.